# Fill in text boxes that have variable ids in Selenium Web Driver

Tags: php, codeigniter, selenium

I am trying to create some automated tests for a website that was built using Codeigniter as a framework.  The site allows a users to create a powerpoint presentation online.  I am trying to create automated tests that test the full process of creating a new presentation, but I have run into an issue creating tests.

The text boxes in the site have variable id's from presentation to presentation. So, in one presentation, the ids might be 'textbox1, textbox2, textbox3, etc' but when you create a new presentation, the textboxes on the same scree may be named 'textbox9, textbox10, textbox11'.

How can I get my tests to work with these variable text box names?  I am a beginner with Selenium Web Driver and haven't found a way to do it yet.  I may need to change how I test this.

Answer (score 1):

You can find those textboxes using XPath.

C# sample (I imagine that it's almost the same in php):

```
driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[contains(@id, 'textbox')]"));
```

You can leave the * to match any tag, or change it to specify any tag you want, e.g. input.